# Calculate Variance of a Group data

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a table contain height and frequency.I want to calculate the variance of it.

> Height  140 150 160 170 180 190
>   Frequency 3 5 57 63 30 2

*I have tried the below code:*

```
height=[140 150 160 170 180 190;3 5 57 63 30 2]

height=height(:)                

V = var(height)                      %Calculate Variance

**This give an answer of   5.7316e+03**
```

**while with formula it give an answer of  81.8594. Now please tell me how can i do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use weighted variance:

```
h=height;
var(h(1,:),h(2,:))
```

Comment: there is not any build in function to do this ?? as i already do it manually

Comment: Turns out there is a build in function, check my edit.